# Big-O Time Complexity of algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is the big-O time complexity of an algorithm that prints all bit strings of length $n$? Select all answers that satisfy the big-O notation. Assume that one bit is printed in constant time, and the complexity of generating each bit string is of the same order as printing it.

Would the answer be:

- $O(n)$
- $O(n^2)$
- $O(2^n)$
- $O(n-2^n)$
- $O(n^2-2^n)$

?

The only other choice is $O(1)$.
I'm a bit lost on this one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @SplitInfinity , you helped the other day on a Big-O question. Am I right in thinking that the last three choices are correct?

Answer (score 1):

A bit has $2$ possible states $1$ or $0$. This means the the number of strings needed to be generated is $2^n$. We then have to go through the string $2$ times: once to generate, and once to read. This gives us a time on $O(2^{n+1}) = O(2^n)$.

Comment: So, I assume that $O(n-2^n)$ and $O(n^2-2^n)$ are also answers? (The assignment asks for more than one answer.) @J. Bush

Comment: @ComputerScienceStudent Yes.